# Rails location of model with two words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I am doing an API backend in Ruby on rails.

I have a model, call it `TestModel`. When a user creates a new record of this method, I want to return a `location` Header containing the URL of the newly created object (i.e. where the user can access it by using GET), so I try

```
render json: @test_model, status: :created, location: @test_model
```

Unfortunately, rails can't give me the location, because he seems to try to call a method `test_model_url`, which rails seems to interpret as the URL for an object `model` as a subobject of an item `test`.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: have you tried this `location: test_model_url(@test_model)` ?

Comment: Yes. It responds with `undefined method `test_model_url`

Comment: This sounds like something caused by a typographical error - make sure your model naming is correct and the routes etc are correct. Because I doubt that it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with the model naming, but more with how ruby on rails work by convention. cf. the [rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) (especially part 2.3)

> Each of these helpers has a corresponding _url helper (such as photos_url) which returns the same path prefixed with the current host, port and path prefix.

-> you have to setup your routes correctly, then _url and _path helpers will work.

you should also stick to the [rails naming conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions), so your model should be named `TestModel` instead of `testModel`.

Comment: I actually named my model `TestModel`, that was just a typo. So now I have a route `resources :test_model`, and I want to get an URL like `http://myhost.com/test_model/:id`, so I try to call `test_model_url`, but he seems to try to find a route like `test/:id/model` which doesn't exists

Comment: i think it should be `resources :test_models`. you can run `rake routes` to see what routes are setup.

Comment: Again, just mistyped. I used `resources :test_models`

Comment: okay, to clarify, when you say API backend, you are referring to a stripped down Rails API project (as in a missing several useful modules version of rails)?